# The type arguments for method '' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Tags: c#, linq

While doing this one

```
IEnumerable<Colors> c = db.Products.Where(t => t.ProductID == p.ProductID).SelectMany(s => s.Colors);
if (c.Any()) sp.color = Constructor(c);
```

and later on

```
private string Constructor<T>(List<T> list)
{
     //Do something
}
```

i get the error

> The type arguments for method
>   'Controller.Constructor(System.Collections.Generic.List)' cannot
>   be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

Of course it is not correct. But what am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Constructor<T>()` method you expect a `List<T>` type but you provide an instance of `IEnumerable<T>`.

- change the method parameter type to `IEnumerable<T>`
- convert to query to `List<T>` type

```cs
IEnumerable<Colors> c =
    db
        .Products
        .Where(t => t.ProductID == p.ProductID)
        .SelectMany(s => s.Colors)
        .ToList();

if (c.Any()) sp.color = Constructor(c);

private string Constructor<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Constructor expects concrete type (`List<T>`) and you pass it interface (`IEnumerable<T>`). Imagine that under `IEnumerable<T>` there is something like `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` - how would you cast that to List? You cannot. So if you don't use anything List-specific in your Constructor, change signature to:

```
private string Constructor<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
 //Do something
}
```

Otherwise - convert your Colors to list via `.ToList()` extension method:

```
if (c.Any()) sp.color = Constructor(c.ToList());
```